# Deserialize flattened JSON keys to proper objects with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

We ingest an external API (we cannot change the JSON we receive) which produces JSON with flattened keys.  For example:

```
{
    "composite.key": "value",
    "normal": "another value",
    "composite.key2": "back here again..."
}
```

which we would ideally like to deserialize into:

```
public class SomeObject {
    public String normal;
    public Composite composite;
}

public class Composite {
    public String key;
    public String key2;
}
```

while we know we can write a custom deserializer, I would first like to check if there is support for this in GSON using annotations or by some other means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the long and short of this is to just use Jackson which provides built-in support by annotating the wrapping object with `@JsonUnwrapped(prefix="composite.")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GSON's [@SerializedName](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) annotation on the Java fields.

Something like this

```
public class Composite {
    @SerializedName("composite.key")
    public String key;

    @SerializedName("composite.key2")
    public String key2;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that works, as the `Composite` object in `SomeObject` never gets deserialized, since there is never a match for the key `composite`.

Comment: @NicoHuysamen Yeah missed that, I think custom deserialization is the way.

Comment: Nah, just opted for using Jackson which has support for this.